# How to import .env variables into variables.scss in vite 5.0

Tags: javascript, sass, build, vuejs3, vite

So guys I have a requirement where I will get the theme (color,font) from user and we need to add it in our .env file and build it with the theme.So how to write it in .env and and after building it the default will be set if the user doesn't have any theme set
tried this

```
    //vite-plugin-scss-env
    export default function scssPlugin() {
      return {
        name: "scss-transform",
        transform(src, id) {
          if (/\.(scss)$/.test(id)) {
            return src.replace(/(\$[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g, (match, p1) => {
              const variableName = p1.substring(1); // Remove the leading '$' symbol
              return env[variableName] || match; // Replace with value from env or keep the original match
            });
          }
        },
      };
    }
I tried to create a plugin which replaces scss variables with value from .env

    //vite.config.js
    import { defineConfig } from "vite";
    import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
    import scssPlugin from "./vite-plugin-scss-env";
    export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue(), scssPlugin()],
    });
```